# Get value from shortcode to do something

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, variables, parameter

For a project I want to use advanced shortcodes. Normally I define shortcodes within my PHP. This way it is always the information I have in my PHP-files that I show with my shortcodes (like [shortcode]). In this project the traffic is different. I need to get information inside in my shortcode that I need to use in a variable in my PHP. This so I can use in my Wordpress editor shortcodes like [shortcode "1"] or [shortcode "2"]. This value from within the "" is a value that I will use to do something in my PHP. This way I don't need to make several shortcodes with countless options but will be way more clean. It will become a kindoff template.

I know it is possible but I don't know how. I have no experience with this kind of traffic and can't find any documentation about this. Hope you guys can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the solution for this case at https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Answer (score 0):

I think Shortcodes with Parameters is what you’re looking for.

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/